# Is `a++ & f(a)` undefined or unspecified?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

This is an example from [Deep C](http://www.slideshare.net/olvemaudal/deep-c) (slide 194)

```
int a = 41;
a++ & printf("%d\n", a);
```

The presentation claims that the result is undefined. Why? `a` is only assigned once between the sequence points. I think that the execution order between `a++` and `printf` would be unspecified, so that this would print either 41 or 42 on all conforming compilers, with no undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line - `a++ & printf("%d\n", a);` there is only one sequence point (not counting what happens in function arguments - since `a++1` happens in this line itself) - modifying a variable and reading from it at the same time within a single seqeunce point is UB. Behavior is undefined if a previous value is read from the object but there is a modification too, as in `i * i++`

`&&` is a sequence point, `&` is not a sequence point if that is where you were confused.

A sequence point is a point in time at which the dust has settled and all side effects which have been seen so far are guaranteed to be complete. The sequence points listed in the C standard are:

> at the end of the evaluation of a full expression (a full
>   expression is an expression statement, or any other expression which
>   is not a subexpression within any larger expression);
>       at the ||, &&, ?:, and comma operators; and
>       at a function call (after the evaluation of all the arguments, and just before the actual call).

The Standard states that

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its
>   stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.
>   Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the
>   value to be stored.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that we can't both modify and read between sequence points. (Apparently the following slides explained that)

Comment: @Andreas - It took me long time to understand this as UB as well :)

Comment: There are two sequence points directly in `a++ & printf("%d\n", a);`. There is sequence point after evaluating `printf` and its arguments but before the actual call, as well as the one at the end of the full expression.

Answer (score 3):

The bitwise operator `&` doesn't introduce a sequence point, so that is indeed undefined behavior.

Comment: I know that. We are still only assigning to it once.

Comment: @Andreas - Modifying a variable and reading from it at the same time within a single seqeunce point is UB.

Comment: “Within a single sequence point” makes Euclid roll in his grave. A point has no part: no width, length, or breadth.

Comment: A point has to be infinitesimal (infinitely small) to have no dimension. There are alternative approaches to Euclidean geometry. If there can be something infinitely small then there can also be something within a point.